# Is "S + think + O + O.C." grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

I saw the sentence "Jake thinks his sister very smart" on a grammar worksheet. However, I have never seen this form of sentence before, nor are there any instances of "S + think + O + O.C" on Google. Which comes to the question: Is it grammatical?

Comment: The basic form is occasionally used, but in the above context it is not very idiomatic.

Comment: _Jake thinks his teacher rather slow_ is better.

Comment: It's OK. "Think" is one of the verbs that can occur in complex-transitives with depictive PCs. "Think" means "consider", which is the preferred verb for some speakers.

Comment: It would be more common to say "Jake thinks his sister's very smart" (or "Jake thinks his sister is very smart") but as others say, the original is grammatical.

Comment: We usually reserve this fancy structure for high-tone cases. She thinks herself better than  her peers. They think their aims loftier than their adversary's.

Comment: The form without some form of the verb 'to be' in it used to be more idiomatic than it is now. An example is in the words of the traditional ballad "The House Carpenter" where the female character says "I am married to a house carpenter and I think him a nice young man". This ballad is probably from the17th century and the way that the phrase is used indicates that the form was absolutely normal at the time.